# IIS URL rewrite rule - query string issue

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, asp-classic, web-config

I have the following URL rewrite rule configured in my web.config file:

```
<rule name="Test Rule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".*item=1|all|none|first.*" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/newsite/test.asp?{C:0}" />
</rule>
```

The following source url matches as expected:

```
http://domainname?item=1
```

However the query string parameter "item" is duplicated in the rewritten URL i.e. the resulting query string is "item=1&item=1". I don't know why it is being duplicated. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `appendQueryString="false"` to the action attribute? Like this:

```
<rule name="Test Rule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".*item=1|all|none|first.*" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/newsite/test.asp?{C:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```